# Solution to parameter dependent heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

---

**The Question:**

Let $p\in [1,\infty)$.

I'm looking for a function $f(t)$ such that $u(x,t):=f(t)cos(x)^p$ solves the following heat equation:
\begin{align}
u_t & = \frac{u_{xx}}{2}
\end{align}

---

**So far, if $p=1$:**

If $p=1$ then I can use $u(x,t)=e^{t/2}cos(x)$, however I'm having difficulty identifying a solution for larger $p$...

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work except when $p=1$; look up separable solutions to the heat equation for details.

Comment: I changed the question it might be possible to solve (non-trivially) now.

Comment: I don't understand, you can't specify $u_x$ at all $(x,t)$...

Comment: I returned it to the initial question... I think there is no solution you're right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form of $u$ has $$\begin{align} 
    u_t(x,t) &= f'(t) \cos^p(x) \\ 
    \frac{1}{2} u_{xx}(x,t) &= \frac{1}{2} f(t) \left( p(p-1)\sin^2(x)\cos^{p-2}(x) - p\cos^p(x) \right)  \\
        &= \left(  \frac{1}{\alpha}  f(t) \right) \left( \frac{\alpha}{2} \left( p(p-1)\sin^2(x)\cos^{p-2}(x) - p\cos^p(x) \right) \right),
\end{align}$$ for any constant $\alpha$.  This produces the system of equations
$$\begin{align} 
    f'(t) &= \frac{1}{\alpha}  f(t)  \\
    \cos^p(x) &= \frac{\alpha}{2} \left( p(p-1)\sin^2(x)\cos^{p-2}(x) - p\cos^p(x) \right).
\end{align}$$  We'll come back to the first of these.  We may divide through by $\cos^p(x)$ to rewrite the second as $$
    1 = \frac{\alpha p}{2} \left( (p-1)\tan^2(x) - 1 \right), 
$$ which is hopeless unless $p=1$.  (For any other choice of $p$, the right-hand side varies with $x$ but the left hand side doesn't.)  For $p=1$, the equation in $x$ reduces to $$
\cos(x) = \frac{-\alpha}{2} \cos(x), 
$$ clearly requiring $\alpha = -2$, so the equation in $t$ is $f' = (-1/2) f$, so $f(t) = f(0) \mathrm{e}^{-t/2}$.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I guess the PDE approach won't solve my problem... but Girsanov's theorem will work (I was trying to find an easy way to solve a certain SDE).  Thanks for all your help guys :)